# Getting error: Oops, there was an error rendering Canvas application [Conga_Composer]. Your browsing session has ended or is invalid

Tags: conga-composer

I was getting this error when access links to Conga Composer from Salesforce buttons.

Oops, there was an error rendering Canvas application [Conga_Composer].
Your browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please re-login to Salesforce.com again.

I could not find the solution online, other than the "clear your browser's cache". I thought I had done this by using Chrome > Clear browsing data, but that did not work.

I am posting this question so I can answer it with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to go into Chrome preferences, Privacy and Security, Site settings, View permissions and data stored across sites, and then I had to open up the twisties and look for anything involving the URLs I was accessing. When I deleted the data, it worked again.